# How to read cucumber feature name from feature file during runtime using latest cucumber version with io.cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

With info.cucumber version i used to have this code to read feature name from feature file during runtime and it was working fine

```
**private String getFeatureFileNameFromScenarioId(Scenario scenario) {
String featureName = "Feature ";
String Feature = scenario.getId().split(";")[0].replace("-"," ");
return Feature;
}**
```

After upgrading cucumber version with list of dependencies which is latest out there

```
**io.cucumber cucumber-core 5.0.0-RC1 compile io.cucumber cucumber-java 5.0.0-RC1 compile io.cucumber cucumber-java8 5.0.0-RC1 compile io.cucumber cucumber-junit 5.0.0-RC1 compile io.cucumber cucumber-testng 5.0.0-RC1 compile**
```

The above code has stopped working and not returning "Feature name from feature file" during runtime.

Can someone out there please help suggest solution on this.

Comment: Have you tried with `scenario.getName()`?

Comment: Yes it didn't work. That works if you have info.cucumber version but not with io.cucumber

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is still relevant but I got it by using:

```
 /**
 * Extracts the feature name from the feature file.
 *
 * @param filePath the path of feature file.
 * @return String feature name or empty if encounters an error.
 */
public static String getFeatureName(String filePath) {
    final String FEATURE_PATTERN = "Feature:";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    try {
        List<String> data = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
        for(String line : data) {
            if(line.contains(FEATURE_PATTERN))
                return line.substring(FEATURE_PATTERN.length());  //get everything after feature pattern
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Cucumber version: 6.11.0